# Single Page HTML Site - SEO technique

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, seo, google-search

I developed a Single Page Responsive Website for my company http://germin8.com/ . Everything is going good however I actually now face a problem with SEO .The site's different sections do not show up in search engine.

I know the cause it being a single page site so not crawler friendly...Inorder to get the URL change I used history pushstate technique and have put href links for menu bar items to sections ..... confused ?? eh
Sample anchor tag outlink ( I thought this is enough for my section to show up in Search Engine :-/ )

```
a style="text-decoration:none;color:black;padding-left:30px;" class="scrollTo" id="contactUs_Menu"
                            href="/contact-us">CONTACT</a></li>
```

Or you may have a look at the source code of the website and follow the anchor tags.

On some research and POC I came across this AJAX crawlable technique by google (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling ) ...however I couldn't understand it and also feel loading site's sections through ajax would be a lot more work at this stage since my entire site is a static HTML file ( index.php ) with nothing rendered dynamically through javascript/AJAX

Someone who has faced similar problem can you suggest me the simplest and fastest way for my site's different sections ( eg .Clients , Partners , Contact Us etc ) to show up in google engine

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: When did the site go live? Maybe you just need to give the search engines some time.

Comment: been 3 weeks since its live.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Hi John how is it off-topic when I have tagged SEO as topic and my title also says SEO :P

Comment: Exactly. @JohnConde How can a question that is about such a popular tag be off topic? What would you say the tag does? What is its purpose?

Comment: Did anybody bother to actually click on the SEO tag and read it? :)

Comment: @JohnConde Yes, why? You mean you missed the part where Zohaib asked about AJAX?

Comment: The core of this question is SEO. Just because JavaScript is mentioned doesn't make this a programming question.

Comment: Hi John , I am still trying to understand what are you trying to convey. Sorry for my lack of understanding. However a JS/AJAX solution is also a part of SEO if I am not wrong :) .

Answer (score 1):

Actually this question is more suitable for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ but since it has been raised here, I'll try and answer this question to the best of my knowledge.

Unfortunately, there is no shortcut for **SEO** and to be able to fetch search results in your favor is a slow and painful process. The basic principle of SEO is doing simple things right and provide quality content to your users in your website and not worry much about the ranking.

That being said, your expectation is slightly unrealistic for the following reasons,

- You are asking Google to index a page that doesn't even exist.
- The URL is changed with JavaScript on runtime, which is something no-search-enginebot is good at indexing.

However, there are couple of things that [you can improve in terms of SEO](https://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) (not going to guarantee what you have asked),

- Make sure you have [sitemap.xml](http://germin8.com/sitemap.xml) file in the root directory of your website. You need to add individual sub-page links for each url like this,

  ```
  <url>
      <loc>http://germin8.com/clients</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  ```

Once you are done with `sitemap.xml` file. Open your Google Webmaster Account (also make sure your Google Analytics account is linked to your webmaster profile) and validate the structure and schema of the sitemap file.

- **Write better anchor text** - Add `title` attribute to your anchor tags. Avoid inline styles as much as you can. Use complete url instead of relative paths for `href` attribute.
- [Google doesn't like slow websites](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/site-speed/). Hence, you need to focus a lot on the performance of your website. Also no user likes to see a webpage loading for ages. Make efforts to concatenate, minify and lint your assets(html/css/js). Gzip compression is required as well.

[image: 4.1MB is huge]

149 requests with 4.1 MB is huge. You need to reduce the number of HTTP requests you make massively!

**Conclusion**

Apart from the above, I don't really see **your internal links not being visible on search results** as a big problem. Your primary objective is to make sure that your users land on your webpage (this is something that you already doing). After the user enters your territory (website) he has the liberty to navigate to any section of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://germin8.com&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&strip=1

I dont see any problem with indexing of your site. Clients will not showup in normal search but they would show up in google images. You should give alt tag to best describe the client images that you have used. Above url will give you an idea how Google bot sees your site. So you can notice all text is indexed by google including your heading where clients are listed. Hope this solves your concern.

Comment: Hi Kamesh. thats really nice and a bit confidence booster for me that it did get indexed by Google bot. My concern is when I type 'germin8 Contact' in google then the search should show germin8.com/contact-us and similarly other sections like germin8.com/clients or germin8.com/services etc.

Comment: For that you will have to create static pages with these urls... Or hide this contact info and client info from Homepage content. Since that info is available right away google will not show it explicitly..Since the Change in Url is simply due to anchor rather than new pages contact, clients will not be considered as unique. Although If you explicitly place these anchors at the top then user can jump to contact info directly from the search results page. Try searching for "History of White House" and look for result from Wikipedia how its displayed. You can show up something similar.